# Determine whether n is the hypotenuse of a triangle having integral sides

Tags: algorithm, math

My algorithm and the ones found in a *possible* duplicate are `O(n)` and too slow for the requirement.

1 <= n <= 5*10^6

Comment: Um trying every number from `i=1 to n-1` checking if `SQRT(n^2 - i^2)` is integral is an O(n) algorithm, though far from the fastest.

Comment: I need a faster solution than O(n) here..

Comment: what are the lower and upper limits of the **n** ?

Comment: The obvious algorithm is `O(n^0.5)` - search numbers `i` up to `(n/2)^0.5` and see if `n - i^2` is square.

Comment: That only 5 million values. An O(1) solution is to just precompute them.

Comment: @PaulBoddington could you please post this as an answer? i have some doubts.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan If you have some doubts, why do you want me to post it as an answer?

Comment: @PaulBoddington So that we can possibly discuss it in the comments?

Comment: How can your solution be O(N) ? Can you describe it ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I do `i1=0` and `i2=n-1`, then I increase `i1` or decrease `i2` according as the sum of their squares is greater than or less than `n*n`. if `i2` becomes less than `i1`, `n` cannot be the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan: sorry, I was confusing between n and n².

Comment: @AnukulSangwan You're right my comment is nonsense. I was solving `a^2 + b^2 = n` for some reason.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan See my corrected answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) tells us that every Pythagorean triple (a, b, c) is formed from integer k, n,m, with m>n

```
a=k*(m^2-n^2)
b=2*k*m*n
c=k*(m^2+n^2)
```

And C is hypotenuse of some right triangle with integral sides, if it could be represented as product of integer k and sum of two non-equal integer squares. We can find prime factors of C and check that at least one factor is [Pythagorean prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_prime) of form 4*p+1. It requires O(Sqrt(C)) time

Comment: Actually, as noted in the article, that formula does *not* generate all possible Pythagorean triples.  It will work however if you remove any common factors from `a, b, c` first so that they are co-prime.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You are right, I considered that fact as inessential for reverse problem, but I was wrong. Corrected.

Comment: Why will it take `O(sqrt(C))` time? What if the one prime factor which is of form `4*p+1` is greater than `sqrt(C)`? I understand that I can check if `n/i` is of form `4*p+1`, but what about the case where `n=5`? I will have to iterate till `n` in that case, so it looks like `O(n)` to me.

Comment: @Anukul Sangwan You need about Sqrt(C) time to get ALL the prime factors with the simplest trial-divide method and better time with more sophisticated factorization methods. Note that if big prime factor exists, it will be calculated before Sqrt(C) reached 111-> divide by 3 -> get 37

Answer (score 2):

As, @MBo has already suggested, we just need to check if n has a prime factor of the form 4k+1. This can be done in O(sqrt(n)) time by computing prime factorization of n.

However, if you need to do this for all values in the mentioned range, you can compute all primes of form 4k+1 using sieve. Then mark all multiples of these primes (in the range [1..5*10**6]) as valid hypotenuse.

This algorithm will compute this boolean function for all inputs in roughly O(N log N log log N) (for sieve) + about the same as sieve for second part? Formal analysis will depend on distribution of primes of form 4k+1. I am not sure how such analysis is done.

Whereas, factorization will take O(N sqrt N) time.